# Use a variable with a created name in a function

Tags: r, function, filenames, assign, ffbase

I don't know if what I try to do is possible! I have a matrix of values (Var_sim) and I convert it as an ff object. The name of this object is created with "paste". Now I want to use this object in the function ffload, this is my code:

```
Variables[k] = TEMP
Cell_number[i] = 4095
selected_domains = 1

assign(paste("Mat_",Variables[k],"_",Cell_number[i],"_",selected_domains[j],sep=""),as.ff(Var_sim))
```

Here I have the variable Mat_TEMP_4085_1 as an ff object. I am using that in a loop so I will have various ff objects with various names (different cell_number).I need to use Mat_TEMP_4085_1 (and the others) in a function but I can't just write the name:

```
ffsave(as.name(paste("Mat_",Variables[k],"_",Cell_number[i],"_",selected_domains[j],sep="")), file="Test")
```

I have the following error:

```
Error in ffsave(as.name(paste("Mat_", Variables[k], "_", Cell_number[i],  : 
objet ‘as.name(paste("Mat_", Variables[k], "_", Cell_number[i], "_",     selected_domains[j], sep = ""))’ not found
```

It doesn't recognize the variable. How can I do?

Comment: What's all this 'ff' stuff? From a package? Also, making names and using assign is nearly always wrong, and is likely the cause of your problem. Make _lists_ of things rather than trying to put indexes into names of things.

Comment: Yes ff is a package and I use it because I am working with large data. The function will write each ff file in a folder and after that I can reload them and use one matrix by one. The problem is when I load an ff object, the variable name is the name of the object saved in ffsave. If I put always the same name and I want to load several ff objets, the variable will be overwrited because it will be the same name.

Comment: You can use the `envir` argument to load each one into a different environment and make a list out of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not look like you are using `as.name` right. Simply remove it or wrap `as.character` around it, if you wanted to get the variable value from the string name of the variable use `get`;  *@Spacedman* is right you should prefer lists of names if you can.

```
tt = "rbind"
print(do.call(tt,list(LETTERS))) # works
print(do.call(as.name(tt),list(LETTERS))) # does not work
print(do.call(as.character(as.name(tt)),list(LETTERS))) # works
print(do.call(get("tt"),list(LETTERS))) # works
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Whatever I try I still have the same error (get, as.character(as.name()) or juste paste()). When I just print the code it gives me the name I want but when I need to use it in the function it doesn't recognize it

Comment: I looked at ffsave, looks like you need to specify a list of names: `require(ff); n <- 8e3;
assign( paste(LETTERS[1:3],collapse=""), ff(sample(n, n, TRUE), vmode="integer", length=n, filename="~/test/ABC.ff") );ffsave(list=paste(LETTERS[1:3],collapse=""),file="~/test/another_ABC")`

Comment: Thanks, it works! I needed "list". The names are set by the arguments the user put in the function. I can have almost 500 000 names from different parameters combinations - I think is more complicated to use a list of names